# Cannot call function using this in class

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a class called `Scheduler` which execute a cron job using the module `cron`. I have created a function to get the days difference between two dates, that function is working if I call it outside the cron job iteration otherwise it will return

> TypeError: this.getDaysDifference is not a function

here's my code:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

class Scheduler {

    async start() {

        // HERE WORKING
        console.log(this.getDaysDifference(new Date('2020-03-29'), new Date('2020-03-30')));

        const job = new CronJob('0 */1 * * * *', async function () {
            let messages = await MessageModel.find();
            for (const msg of messages) {
                // HERE NOT WORKING
                console.log(this.getDaysDifference(new Date(), msg.lastScheduler));
            }
        });

        job.start();
    }

    getDaysDifference = function(start, end) {
        const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        const utc1 = Date.UTC(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate());
        const utc2 = Date.UTC(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate());
        return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
    }
}

exports.Scheduler = Scheduler;
```

Comment: Is `await MessageModel.find();` is successful?

Comment: yes, I just not included in the example above 'cause it is not relevant, is just a `mongoose` model that contains a list of messages @brk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this.getDaysDifference` is not pointing to the *instance* of the class `Scheduler` in your callback since you have used a `function`.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Use an arrow function `() => {}` which is very straight forward.
- Bind the `this` to your instance explicitly using a `functionObj.bind(yourInstance)`.

You can use an arrow function that will bind `this` to the *lexical* *this* in your callback definition:

```
new CronJob('0 */1 * * * *', async () => {
     let messages = await MessageModel.find();
     for (const msg of messages) {
         //this will be the lexical  this i.e. point to the instance o sthe Scheduler class
         console.log(this.getDaysDifference(new Date(), msg.lastScheduler));
        }
});
```

Solution using `bind`, where you explicitly bind the value of `this` to the instance of your class:

```
let cronJobCallback = async function () {
      let messages = await MessageModel.find();
      for (const msg of messages) {
      // HERE NOT WORKING
      console.log(that.getDaysDifference(new Date(), msg.lastScheduler));
      }
 }
 cronJobCallback = cronJobCallback.bind(this);
 new CronJob('0 */1 * * * *', cronJobCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks, you have given me some excellent suggestions that will come in handy in the future, I wish you a good day

Answer (score 1):

When the callback given to CronJob is executed it will be in another context and thus `this` will not refer to your `Scheduler` instance (maybe to the `CronJob` instance). Try capturing `this` before making your `CronJob´ sintance:

```
    async start() {

        // HERE WORKING
        console.log(this.getDaysDifference(new Date('2020-03-29'), new Date('2020-03-30')));
        const that = this;
        const job = new CronJob('0 */1 * * * *', async function () {
            let messages = await MessageModel.find();
            for (const msg of messages) {
                // HERE NOT WORKING
                console.log(that.getDaysDifference(new Date(), msg.lastScheduler));
            }
        });

        job.start();
    }
```

Alternative, use an arrow function.